# Query consecutive vocals on sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I had an exam last week and one of the exercises were "Obtain all data of students whom lastnames have at least two consecutive vocals".

I have tried doing the following:

```
select 
    apellidos
from 
    alumnos
where 
    apellidos LIKE '[%aeiou%]'
```

I also tried the query with a lot of ORs.

```
select 
    apellidos
from 
    alumnos
where 
    apellidos LIKE '[%ae%]' 
    OR apellidos LIKE '[%ai%]' 
    OR apellidos LIKE '[%ao%]'
    OR apellidos LIKE '[%au%]' 
    OR apellidos LIKE '[%ei%]' 
    OR apellidos LIKE '[%eo%]'
    OR apellidos LIKE '[%eu%]' 
    OR apellidos LIKE '[%io%]' 
    OR apellidos LIKE '[%iu%]'
    OR apellidos LIKE '[%ou%]'
```

None of this works, please help!

Comment: Can you post some data examples?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming "vocal" means "vowel" you want something like:

```
where apellidos LIKE '%[aeiou][aeiou]%'
```

You should practice your pattern matching with `like`.  Then you can move on to real regular expressions.

Comment: Hello! thanks! that helped a lot, do you have a website where I can find regular expressions training? I realize that's a skill I have to acquire.

Comment: @DavidSalasBoscan . . . I would suggest that you Google regular expressions.  You might be able to find material in your native language.